# What is meant by the expression "Jazz pants"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, vocabulary

I just watched a show, and there were competitors arguing with each others then one of them said "Are you happy with it now?" 
and then the woman said "Jazz pants!"

I don't really know the name of the show, sorry. 
It came from a short video clip on the advertising screen in the Mall.
Those competitors were arguing while they were cooking with loud noise, 
that's why I turned around to watch that video and it's ending with that woman said "Jazz pants!" (not *Jazz hands*).

What does "Jazz pants" in this situation mean?

Comment: What show was this? Can you give anymore context? Andrew is probably correct, but with more context it would be easier to know for sure (maybe she meant to say "tap pants", for example).

Comment: Yes, which episode of which show?

Comment: A show about what? The competitors of what? A talent show? An ice-skating show? If you could tell they were competitors then you could tell what type of competition it was. If you can't.... because the clip was so brief then the question is useless because it lacks that essential element, and it should, therefore, be closed IMO. If the clip was so brief, how can you be sure you didn't mishear?

Comment: [**Just Pants**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noZeSKNQa8o) a 1978 commercial for the brand [*just pants*](https://fiu-assets-2-syitaetz61hl2sa.stackpathdns.com/static/use-media-items/6/5407/full-781x1024/56701ba7/6237070305_3bd08c2cd2_b.jpeg?resolution=0).

Comment: `while they were cooking with loud noise` Was it a cooking show? Were the competitors "famous" by any chance?

Comment: Possibly, you misheard "that's [pants](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pants&page=3)" ?  Although I think that's more of a UK expression than US (where are you based?)

Comment: @NathanTuggy  Deleting that word which says "update" harms the user who wrote suggesting jazz hands in the first place. It now seems that the OP did not clarify ***after*** Andrew posted their answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think that removing "update" harms Andrew's answer - he has edited it since Nathan cleaned up the question and it seems fine to me. The revision history has the exact timeline for anyone to see.

Answer (score 22):

Is it possible you misheard?  A not-uncommon (American) expression is "jazz hands" to indicate excitement:

[image]

usually ironically:

[image]

To do it right, you should make the "jazz hands" gesture as you say, with some enthusiasm, "Jazz Hands!"

[More about the fabulous history of "jazz hands"](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/the-fabulous-history-of-jazz-hands)

---

(Edit) If you are *certain* that the person said "jazz pants", then I have no idea what it could mean.  "Jazz pants" are light, tight pants, used in "jazz dance" routines, usually black, made from some kind of stretchy fabric, and commonly flared at the bottom:

[image]

It makes no sense to reference dancewear on a cooking show, and I know of no idiomatic alternate meaning of "jazz pants".

Comment: I've never thought of it as excitement, even when not used ironically. I mean, when in the last 80 yeas has jazz hands been used unironically? To me it's a satire of the melodrama of the performing arts. Actually making that move in a dance today would be seen as hopelessly quaint unless it were a joke. All that said, I now want to make "jazz pants" an expression somehow.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Deaf people use jazz hands unironically as "applause" because they can't hear hand clapping.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_hands  The term became ironic after Bob Fosse "overused" the technique

Comment: @CanadianYankee the deaf "applause" sign isn't quite the same as Jazz Hands in my (somewhat limited) experience.  The former is more upright, and raised to or even above head level, while the latter is angled as in the "The Office" example shown here.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I'm pretty sure it's been one for a long time! Check out the outro of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIUvR5JTB3c) (starting at 2:12, and again at 5:00 onward). Then again, maybe that's just a [mondegreen](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mondegreen.html) :-)

Comment: @ToddWilcox It's a shame, because [Bob Fosse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Fosse)'s work was very innovative at the time. I suppose almost every great innovator has some of their work end up as a cliche :(

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't state a location, I will suggest that it if was in the UK, 
you may have misheard "that's [pants](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pants&page=3)" or "just pants".

"Pants", meaning underpants, is a derogatory term used in the UK, meaning something like "rubbish" or "nonsense".

You say

> Those competitors were arguing ... then one of them said "Are you happy with it now?" and then the woman said "Jazz pants!"

If it were "just pants!", it could have been her opinion of someone else's statement.

---

If you go back to the mall, please let us know what you hear next time.